# not a statement error

Tags: java

I was creating a calculator in Java using Netbeans, When I try to compile,
I get an error saying, "Not a statement"

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    a * Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    b * Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
    c * a * b;
    jTextField3.setText(" " + c);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably mean for these lines:

```
a*Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
b*Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
c*a*b;
```

to be something like:

```
a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
c = a*b;
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
a*Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
```

is just performing the multiplication - it isn't assigning the value to anything. That's not a valid statement in Java. (It's also trying to use an unassigned variable.)

I *suspect* you want to use assignment, like this:

```
int a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
int b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
int c = a * b;
```

Note the use of the assignment operator (`=`) where you previously had `*`.

I've also declared the variables at the point of first use, which is generally a good practice. It's not strictly *required*, mind you:

```
// Valid but not as nice code.
int a;
int b;
int c;
a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
b = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());
c = a * b;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid

```
a*Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
```

is not an instantiation. Try

```
a = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
```

instead, it may help to get one line further in this task.